# Marker locations can't be retrieve from database

Tags: android, sqlite, sugarorm

I am having a trouble showing the `marker` in the map while in offline mode. I used sugar orm to handle the database manipulation. I used the code below.

```
DataResponse responseNiDatabase = new Gson().fromJson(JSON_STRING, DataResponse.class);

    List<Result> markersFromDatabase = new ArrayList<>();

   if (responseNiDatabase != null){

       markersFromDatabase = responseNiDatabase.getResult();
       SugarRecord.saveInTx(markersFromDatabase);
   }
   else{
       Toast.makeText(this, "An error occured, fetching from database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       markersFromDatabase = Select.from(Result.class).list();
   }

    if (!markersFromDatabase.isEmpty()){
        for (Result resultFromResponse : markersFromDatabase){
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(resultFromResponse.getLatitude()),
                    Double.parseDouble(resultFromResponse.getLongitude())))
                    .title(resultFromResponse.getShopName())
                    .snippet(resultFromResponse.getShopContact())
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon)));
        }
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "No markers available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Whenever I connect to the internet, all data from the server will be retrieved and stored in the local database. The thing is, I can't figure why its not retrieving the data from the local database when in offline mode. This is my first time using sugar orm library, so I hope someone out there could help me with this. Thank you.

PS. I'm using google api.

Comment: Have you logged your  'markersFromDatabase' value list before if (!markersFromDatabase.isEmpty()) this line

Comment: Yes. Every data was saved in the database, as viewed in the logcat in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Making the assumption that you are definitely saving your data correctly, try changing this:

```
markersFromDatabase = Select.from(Result.class).list();
```

to:

```
markersFromDatabase = Result.listAll(Result.class);
```

They really should be the same thing, but I've found there are some undocumented little catches all over Sugar.